# How to programatically add files to the Plupload queue?

Tags: plupload

Since my previous question wasn't answered, let me put it in a different way.
I would like someone to provide a functional example on how to programatically add a file to plupload queue, ready for uploading.
Perhaps something like this:

```
$('#uploader').on("ready", function() { 
    uploader.addFile("c:\\file.jpg");
});
```

This code isn't working, though.
Thanks.

EDIT:
Following Elijah Lynn's answer, I edited my code example to load a file from the server, not from the client.

```
$('#uploader').on("ready", function() { 
    uploader.addFile("server_path/file.jpg");
});
```

Comment: That's because your questions tend to be code requests.  Code requests are OK, as long as the code you're asking for is useful to others.  So far, though, your questions seem to be very specific to your particular programming scenario.  Learning a system one SO question at a time is not a viable strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I just attempted to do this and I don't think it is possible to do this. The reason being security. Imagine if you created a script like you suggest with a link to a picture and just loaded it on 100,000 clients. One of those clients might just have a link to that photo and off it would go to your website! And you wouldn't have needed their permission.

That being said, there is an addFile() method that Plupload provides but it needs a File object and getting that File object programatically is the forbidden part. The core issue is getting the File reference in order to then get the File object.

Comment: thank you for your answer, you are right, but I managed to do that using the addFile() method to auto-load images from the server, not from the client. My question was not properly asked, sorry.

Comment: Would you mind providing an answer to this question with a functional example?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
const file = item.getAsFile();

$('#uploader').pluploadQueue().addFile(file, file.name)
// It might just be for you
uploader.addFile(file, file.name)
```

You can get more info here
https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Uploader#addFile-method-filefileName

I do not think you can upload file from your local drive, but you can through a custom drag and drop like you can see here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop

Answer (score 0):

The only code that worked so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    plupload = $("#uploader").plupload('getUploader');
    var img = new mOxie.Image();
    var url = o.resolveUrl("server_path/file.jpg");
    img.onload = function() {
        plupload.addFile(img.getAsBlob());
    }
    img.load(url);
});
```

This auto-loads an image from the server, after the document is ready. The credit for the code above goes to an user called Cinza.

I could not implement Calen's code. Maybe he wants to give us a functional example.